# RoomDatabase.query() with an INSERT statement not committing changes to the database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am executing an SQL INSERT statement on a `RoomDatabase`.
Using `RoomDatabase.query()` for the same. However, unless I call any function on the returned `cursor`, the inserted row is not *committed* to the database -

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String uuid;

    @Embedded
    @NonNull
    private Address address;

    public Person(@NonNull String uuid, @NonNull Address address) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}


public class Address {
    @NonNull
    private String street;

    @NonNull
    private String city;

    public Address(String street, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}

@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Person")
    List<Person> getPersons();
}

@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
@Database(entities = {Person.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class PersonDb extends RoomDatabase {
    private static volatile PersonDb INSTANCE;

    public abstract PersonDao getPersonDao();

    public static PersonDb getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (PersonDb.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            PersonDb.class, "persons.db")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Here is my testcase -

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PersonsIssueTest {
    private final static String TAG = PersonsIssueTest.class.getSimpleName();

    private PersonDb mDb;

    private SimpleSQLiteQuery personsInsertQuery =
            new SimpleSQLiteQuery("INSERT INTO Person (uuid, street, city) " +
                    "VALUES ('1', 'lane', 'york')");

    @After
    public void closeDb() throws IOException {
        mDb.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void insertQueryTest() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        Cursor c;

        mDb = PersonDb.getInstance(context);
        PersonDao dao = mDb.getPersonDao();

        List<Person> persons = dao.getPersons();
        Log.d(TAG, "> number of persons " + persons.size() + " rows");

        Log.d(TAG, "> running: " + personsInsertQuery.getSql());
        c = mDb.query(personsInsertQuery);
        /* If I comment the next statement, number of persons returned is 0 in the following dao.getPersons() */
        c.moveToFirst();
        c.close();

        persons = dao.getPersons();
        Log.d(TAG, "> number of persons " + persons.size() + " rows");
        assertEquals(1, persons.size());
    }

}
```

If I comment `c.moveToFirst()`, number of persons returned is 0 in the following `dao.getPersons()`

Any issue here?

Comment: Use `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().execSQL()`, not `query()`. The behavior that you are seeing is consistent with how `SQLiteDatabase` works with `query()` and `rawQuery()`, though those methods are not designed for use with `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you; I used query() to do an Insert into select from table which is not supported via Dao in Room as of now.

Comment: Could you please point me to any help on why an operation on cursor is necessitated.?

Comment: "I used query() to do an Insert into select from table which is not supported via Dao in Room as of now" -- I would recommend working with the `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` and `SupportSQLiteDatabase`. You get those by `getOpenHelper()` and `getWritableDatabase()`, respectively, as noted in my first comment. "Could you please point me to any help on why an operation on cursor is necessitated.?" -- `query()` and `rawQuery()` on `SQLiteDatabase` lazy-evaluate. `SupportSQLiteDatabase` implementations will tend to work the same way.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you .

Comment: @CommonsWare you save my day. It works for room  database the syntax would be

myRoomDatabase.openHelper.writeableDatabase.execSQL("your insert/update/delete query")